# Is the minimum cross sectional area of the wire right?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stress-strain

[image]

The breaking stress of the wire is $3.5\times 10^6 \,N/m^2$. It is observed that the minimum cross-sectional area of the wire so that it does not break is $18.67 \,cm^2$. Now I need to find out if the observation is right or not.

At first, I have calculated the acceleration of the blocks. It is $3.267\, m/s^2$. I don't whether it is useful or not in this regard.

We now that, $\displaystyle\text{Stress}= \frac{F}{\text{Area}}\,\text{or}\,\text{Area}=\frac{F}{\text{Stress}}$. I think I can get the area with this equation. Am I right?

How can I calculate $F$ here? Is it $5g+ 10g$? Or what? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate tension ($F$) in the string. So $$ A_{min}=\frac{F}{\text{(Stress)}_{max}}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Doubtnut. I am having problem in calculating the F. Is it 5g+10g? Or what? Please help.

Comment: That you have to calculate. We don't provide direct solution on this site. BTW, it is not?

Comment: Then is it (m1+m2)*(g-a)? I think it may work. What do you think?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWmkgLtIRIo) may help you.

Comment: So, what I have understood from the video is F will be equals to 2M1M2g/(M1+M2). Am I right, @Doubtnut? Please answer.

Comment: Yes, you got it.